# jQuery Ajax JSON not returning any Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a simple Ajax function:

```
insertInto = function(){

    console.log("Hello ");


    var power = $("#power").val();
    var vehicle = $("#vehicle").val();
    var sendData = { "power": power, "vehicle": vehicle };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://192.168.15.42//Test/www/insert.php",
        data: sendData,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data){
            alert("Successfully added!")
            } else {
            alert ("else!")
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("error")
        }
    });
}
```

In `insert.php` if I do:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data =  ['status'=>'Ok'];

return json_encode($data);

?>
```

**I get success and I get the Response {Status => Ok}**

If I do:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('connect.php');

$power=$_POST["power"];
$vehicle=$_POST["vehicle"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO practicetbl (power,vehicle) VALUES ('$power' , '$vehicle')";

return json_encode($sql);

?>
```

**I get the response but I get the error function.(the data is inserted).**

And If I do:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('connect.php');
$data =  ['status'=>'Ok'];

$power=$_POST["power"];
$vehicle=$_POST["vehicle"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO practicetbl (power,vehicle) VALUES ('$power' , '$vehicle')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $success =  "New record created successfully";
    echo json_encode($success);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

return json_encode($sql);

?>
```

**The data is inserted, but I don't get the response and my insert.php script is being cancelled in the console...**

I Image the problem Is with JSON. But why is this happening if I am returning the JSON values?

Comment: comment this line `echo json_encode($success);` from your code!!

Comment: It doesnt work no matter if i remove these lines

Comment: Please check ajax response. If your PHP query return error, you should post it.

Comment: The response is 200. I insert fields in to the database, I just dont get the correct headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
        foobar(data);
    },

//Place outside insertInto
function foobar(data) {
  if(data){
    alert("Successfully added!")
  } else {
    alert ("else!")
  }
}
```